# Xbox Series X Dev Mode Media Capture/Remote View

Tags: uwp, remote-desktop, xbox, dev-mode, mediacapture

I'am developping UWP apps on a Xbox Series X in Dev Mode and i need to be able to record the test i am doing for validation purpose.

With the xbox series x in dev mode the previously available(On Xbox One) Media Capture section is not available anymore. I'm also not able to see what is hapening on my xbox with my PC. (Remote Sharing with "Xbox Console Companion".

Is there a way to record what is happening on screen or maybe view what is happening from a PC ?

Regards, Daniel.

Comment: I’m little confused. Do you want to record a video by using an app in Xbox Series X , or implement a capture videos function in your UWP app?

Comment: I want to record a video of my xbox series X screen using an app. The app can be external like a remote viewer.

Comment: You could try to use [Xbox Dev Mode Companion(Preview)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xbox-dev-mode-companion-preview/9nblggh519cp?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) to view what is happening on the console from a PC.

Comment: I already tried but sadly it doesn't work when my xbox series x is in dev mode. (It connect but only show a black screen)

Comment: You could try to capture screenshots by using the Media Capture tab in [Windows Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/device-portal-xbox). Sometimes rebooting the console will solve the black screen in Xbox Dev Mode Companion, but there’s no guarantee that will work.